# Haskell - Error map function returning a list

Tags: arrays, haskell, dictionary

What I want to do is to apply the `stoline` function on each element (`String`) of the list passed to `stomap`..

Type of `stoline` : `stoline :: String -> [Obj]`.

Here is my code :

```
stomap :: [[String]] -> [Obj]
stomap [[val]] = stoline val
stomap (val:vals) = map (\a -> stoline a) val ++ ...
```

Example of the data passed to `stomap` : `[["0","133","2"],["6","0","0"],["656","0","3"]]`.

**Error** : Couldn't match expected type `Obj` with actual type `[Obj]` in the return type of a call of `stoline`.

The problem is the `map` function which returns a list (and shouldn't!), but I don't really know how to avoid that problem..

Comment: FYI, `[Obj]` is a list, not an array. The semantics and access times are different. For example, lists have O(k) access to the k'th element and arrays have O(1) access to the k'th element.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I fixed it (writing mistake..) ; +1 !

Comment: Well, according to you, stoline takes a string, not a list of strings.

Comment: @LukaHorvat : Yes ! But the `stomap` function is sending a `String` to `stoline`... val is `[String]` and `map` takes each element (so `String`s) of val.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first case is unnecessary, and there's an error is in your second case:

```
map (\a -> stoline a) val ++ ...
```

`val` here is `[String]`, so `map (\a -> stoline a) val` is `[[Obj]]`. Since you're using `++` to combine it with the rest of the results, your ultimate result will be of type `[[Obj]]`, not `[Obj]`.

Let's rework it:

```
stomap :: [[String]] -> [Obj]
stomap lolos = concatMap (\los -> concatMap (\s -> stoline s) los) lolos
```

`lolos` is a list of lists of strings, `los` is a list of strings, and `s` is a string.

We use `concatMap` here, rather than normal `map`, since we want to generate a single list of objects `[Obj]` not a nested list of lists of lists of Objects: `[[[Obj]]]`, and since we're running `stoline` on each `String` in the input, we need to collapse that structure as we traverse `lolos`.

We can clean up the above code (make it more haskelly) by making it point-free.
`\s -> stoline s` is the same as `stoline`, so we could have:

```
stomap lolos = concatMap (\los -> concatMap stoline los) lolos
```

`\los -> concatMap stoline los` is the same as `concatMap stoline`, so we could reduce that to:

```
stomap lolos = concatMap (concatMap stoline) lolos
```

And we can drop the argument from both sides, giving us:

```
stomap = concatMap (concatMap stoline)
```

It may seem illegible at first, but to the experienced haskeller, this can read even more clearly than your original code - it's clear to me that this last version just combines the results of running `stoline` over a list of lists.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this well detailed answer! That solves my problem and the explanation will help me, so answer accepted, of course :) !